is there a way to edit all the commit by user to another user
I discover after a lot of time that the git config is not set and all my work for about year is not in contributions (except making the repo) and when I see the commits I found it all say root authored and root committed and there is no user called root my terminal just makes it to push.
now i edit the git config to my future commits to be with my name and email by this command: git config --global user.email "MY EMAIL"
but now is there any way to get my past commits to be in my contributions and count to be my commits not root commits?
I try to ask ai to help me and it told me to use command git rebase -i --root and edit every world pick with world edit and then edit the user by git commit --amend --author="USERNAME "
but my problem was that I have more than 700 commits so i can't edit it one by one

git filter-repo --mailmap

use git filter-repo here is the doc https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo which is really handy tool for what you want to do
